# タグ情報ページで現在訪問しているタブのタブテキストが見づらい

Tags: バグ, デザイン, ダークモード

ダークモードで[タグ情報ページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags/python/topusers)を閲覧すると、現在訪問しているページのタブの文字色が背景と近い色となっており、見づらい状態になっています。

[image: 現在訪問しているページのタブテキストが黒、背景が紺色となっておりテキストが読みづらい]

また、ダークモードの状態で現在訪問しているタブにマウスホバーすると、タブの背景がライトモード時の色になってしまいます。

[image: 現在いるタブをホバーすると、ダークモードなのにタブの背景がライトモードのときのように白くなっている]

Comment: 英語版でも再現したので MSO にも投稿しておきました。 - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402958 / 他にも似たようなバグが有って、直ってたり対応中だったりする感じのようです。